# Why is $1+O(\frac{(\log n)^2}{n}) = 1-o(1)$?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

I'm always surprised by the ease with which some authors use aymptotics. Here's the example that brought this up for me today: $1+O(\frac{(\log n)^2}{n}) = 1-o(1)$. I'm sure there's nothing too deep here, but can someone explain their line of reasoning when they see expressions like this?

Comment: Because $\frac{(\log n)^2}{n} = o(1)$.

Comment: This is an abuse of notation, at least... if a function is $1 + O((\log n)^2/n)$, it is also $1 - o(1)$, but the converse doesn't hold.  For instance, the function $1 + (\log n)^3 / n$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

One may recall that, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
u_n=o(v_n)
$$ means
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{u_n}{v_n}=0.
$$ Since
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\frac{(\log n)^2}{n}}{1}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(\log n)^2}{n}=0,
$$ then, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
O\left(\frac{(\log n)^2}{n}\right)=o(1).
$$

Comment: This allows me to conclude that $1+O(\frac{(\log n)^2}{n}) = 1+o(1)$, so why the $1-o(1)$? Because $-o(1) = o(1)$?

Comment: @Fequish Exactly!

Comment: I see. So there is some sort of convention to usually write $1-o(1)$ instead of $1+o(1)$. Is there any reason for this convention?